# References for "metric" network flow problems

Tags: linear-programming, reference-request, online-resources, graphs, network-flow

Network flow problems are very well studied in the literature (e.g., see the [Network Flows book](http://mitmgmtfaculty.mit.edu/jorlin/network-flows/)), and [the first DIMACS challenge](http://archive.dimacs.rutgers.edu/Challenges/) was dedicated to these problems.

Very efficient implementation of state-of-the-art algorithms are available, for instance, in the [LEMON graph library](https://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/latest/a00005.html).

However, I am unable find any reference dealing for the special case of “**metric network flow problems**”, that is, for problems where, given the network $G=(N,A)$, the costs coefficients $c_{ij}$ associated to any arc $(i,j) \in A$ define a **distance function**:

1. $c_{ij} \geq 0$ (*non negativity*)
2. $c_{ij} = 0 \iff i=j$
3. $c_{ij} = c_{ji}$ (*symmetry*)
4. $c_{ik} \leq c_{ij} + c_{jk}$ (*triangle inequality*)

Do you know any work related to this case? If yes, does exist standard benchmarks for this case available online?

In particular, I am interested to the *metric* transportation problem and the *metric* minimum cost flow problem.

Comment: Are these helpful? [1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25769287?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents), [2](https://www2.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~disser/pdfs/DisserSkutella18.pdf), [3](https://pemami4911.github.io/cs-dojo/algorithms-geometric-transportation.pdf). I can't find exactly what you're looking for though.

Comment: Reference 3 is very related to my question, and, indeed, my question is motivated by Discrete Optimal Transport applications. I will look it careful, thanks a lot!

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: I think you can write an answer using reference 3, and the references therein contained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following references do not completely answer the idea of a *metric* (that satisfies the triangle inequality) as said by the OP they are still useful.

Under network flow, [Emami (2018)](https://pemami4911.github.io/cs-dojo/algorithms-geometric-transportation.pdf) describes several algorithms that can be used to tackle the geometric transportation problem.

- The *exact geometric algorithm*

> The main contribution of this paper is that, when the ground distance is the $l_1$, $l_2$, or $l_\infty$ norm, the algorithm runs in $\mathcal O(n^{2.5}\log n \log N)$.

The author describes the results by [Atkinson and Vaidya (1995)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01190848) through the [weighted Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_Voronoi_diagram) (WVD). Where this fits into the question is that in such a diagram, the distance between cells can satisfy the standard Euclidean metric.

- The *approximate geometric algorithm*

In fact, there are two such algorithms proposed by [Agarwal *et al.* (2017)](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2017/7234/pdf/LIPIcs-SoCG-2017-7.pdf).

> The first is a randomized $\epsilon$-approximation algorithm that finds the optimal
>   transportation in $\mathcal O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ expected time whose expected cost is $\mathcal O(\log(1/\epsilon))\mu(\tau^*)$ if the spread of $A \cup B$ is bounded by some polynomial. This algorithm uses randomly-shifted grids to recursively decompose the problem into a set of easier subproblems that are solved by Orlin’s algorithm.
>
> The second algorithm described is a $(1 + \epsilon)$ approximation algorithm
>   that finds a transportation plan with cost $(1 + \epsilon)\mu(\tau^*)$ in time
>   $\mathcal O(n^{1.5}\epsilon^{-d}\operatorname{polylog}(U)\operatorname{polylog}(n))$. The algorithm constructs an efficient representation of the pairwise distances between the point sets, and then makes use
>   of Lee and Sidford’s min-cost flow algorithm on the resulting flow graph.

NB There is a post here on OR.SE that explains the difference between [*exact* and *approximate*](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/934/optimization-terminology-exact-v-approximate).

Finally, there is an older paper by [Lim *et al.* (2006)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25769287?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) that studies a transportation problem with *minimum quality commitment* (MQC).

> The transportation problem with MQC can be classified into two classes: the metric version and the non-metric version. The metric version makes the restriction that the transportation costs satisfy the triangular inequality. In other words, in the metric version, $c_{i,j}$ depends on the distance between the location of carrier $i$ and the location of customer $j$ which forms a metric. The metric version is practical in some real applications. [...] This paper focuses on the non-metric version of the transportation problem with MQC; in terms of the computational complexities [...] The other [heuristic] is a greedy heuristic, whose solution quality depends on the scale of the minimum quantity when the transportation cost forms a distance metric.

It is also proven that the transportation problem with MQC and metric transportation costs in $\sf{NP}$-hard.

---

<sub>References</sub>

<sub>[1] Emami, P. (2018). Algorithms for the Geometric Transportation
Problem. Available from: https://pemami4911.github.io/cs-dojo/algorithms-geometric-transportation.pdf.</sub>

<sub>[2] Atkinson, D. S., Vaidya, P. M. (1995) Using geometry to solve the transportation problem in the plane. *Algorithmica.* **13**(5):442–461.</sub>

<sub>[3] Agarwal, P. K., Fox, K., Panigrahi, D., Varadarajan, K. R., Xiao, A. (2017). Faster algorithms for the geometric transportation problem.
*Proceedings of the 33rd International Symposium on Computational
Geometry (SoCG 2017).*</sub>

<sub>[4] Lim, A., Wang, F., Xu, Z. (2006). A Transportation Problem with Minimum Quantity Commitment. *Transportation Science.* **40**(1):117-129.</sub>